# Implementing sampling from GEV distribution from scratch

Tags: distributions, python, sampling

I am trying to implement sampling from GEV distribution without using external libraries (except numpy) and this is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
def gev_rvs(c=-0.583, loc=68.44, scale=66.05, size=1000):
    u = np.random.uniform(size=size)
    sample = loc + scale / c * (np.power(-np.log(u), -c) - 1)
    return sample
```

I am using the equation for the quantile function for GEV as in wikipedia. However when I compare it with the results from

```
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev
sample = gev.rvs(c=-0.583, loc=68.44, scale=66.05, size=1000)
```

they give much different distributions of samples. What could be the reason?

**Update**:
The corrected version of Ben's equation seems to be the same as the one in wikipedia, however they are both far from the one provided by scipy:
[image]

Attaching below the code used for histogram in case I made a mistake somewhere:

```
def wikipedia_gev_rvs(c, loc, scale, size):
    u = np.random.uniform(size=size)
    sample = loc + scale / c * (np.power(-np.log(u), -c) - 1)
    return sample

def ben_gev_rvs(c, loc, scale, size):
    u = np.random.uniform(size=size)
    sample = loc + scale / c * (np.power(np.abs(np.log(u)), -c) - 1)
    return sample

def scipy_gev_rvs(c, loc, scale, size):
    sample = scipy.stats.genextreme.rvs(c, loc, scale, size=size)
    return sample

sample_w = wikipedia_gev_rvs(-0.583, 68.44, 66.05, size=1000)
sample_b = ben_gev_rvs(-0.583, 68.44, 66.05, size=1000)
sample_s = scipy_gev_rvs(-0.583, 68.44, 66.05, size=1000)

plt.hist(sample_w, bins=range(-200, 1500, 20), alpha=0.5, label='wikipedia')
plt.hist(sample_b, bins=range(-200, 1500, 20), alpha=0.5, label='ben')
plt.hist(sample_s, bins=range(-200, 1500, 20), alpha=0.5, label='scipy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I added the comparison of histograms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the difference is in the sign of $c$. This is explained in the notes of the scipy `genextreme` function (source on [GitHub](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py)).

```
Notes
    -----
    For :math:`c=0`, `genextreme` is equal to `gumbel_r` with 
    probability density function

    .. math::

        f(x) = \exp(-\exp(-x)) \exp(-x),

    where :math:`-\infty < x < \infty`.

    For :math:`c \ne 0`, the probability density function for `genextreme` is:

    .. math::
        f(x, c) = \exp(-(1-c x)^{1/c}) (1-c x)^{1/c-1},

    where :math:`-\infty < x \le 1/c` if :math:`c > 0` and 
    :math:`1/c \le x < \infty` if :math:`c < 0`.

    Note that several sources and software packages use the opposite
    convention for the sign of the shape parameter :math:`c`.

    `genextreme` takes ``c`` as a shape parameter for :math:`c`.
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about the source code that I found, as the class genextreme has no rvs defined in it. Anyway, if it is somewhere else it might still be due to that convention about the shape parameter.

Comment: Mystery solved! When changing the sign of **c** it aligns with the scipy version, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I was also looking at their source code before posting the question here, but couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the GEV distribution for the standardised value $s = (x-\mu)/\sigma$.  This distribution has CDF given by:

$$F(s|\xi) = \begin{cases}
\exp(-\exp(-s)) & & & \text{for } \xi=0, \\[6pt]
\exp(-(1+\xi s)^{-1/\xi}) & & & \text{for } s > -1/\xi \ \text{ and } \ \xi \neq 0, \\[6pt]
0 & & & \text{for } s \leqslant -1/\xi \ \text{ and } \ \xi > 0, \\[6pt]
1 & & & \text{for } s \leqslant -1/\xi \ \text{ and } \ \xi < 0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

Inverting this function gives the corresponding quantile function for the standardised value:

$$Q(p|\xi) = \begin{cases}
-\log(-\log(p)) & & & \text{for } \xi=0, \\[6pt]
\frac{1}{\xi} (|\log(p)|^{-\xi}-1) & & & \text{for } \xi \neq 0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

Substituting the original parameters then gives the quantile function for the non-standardised value:

$$Q(p|\mu, \sigma, \xi) = \begin{cases}
\mu - \sigma \log(-\log(p)) & & & \text{for } \xi=0, \\[6pt]
\mu + \frac{\sigma}{\xi} (|\log(p)|^{-\xi}-1) & & & \text{for } \xi \neq 0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

The mathematical form in your code does not appear to correspond to this function, so I suspect that this is the source of the problems you are having.

Comment: I believe that now your current formula corresponds to the OP formula except using an absolute sign instead of negation.

Comment: It seems so to me as well, since **p** is between 0 and 1, then logarithm will be always negative which means adding minus is equivalent to abolute sign, which seems to be confrmed on the histograms when compared.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: Since $0<p<1$ we have $-\log(p) = |\log(p)|$ so this is really just a matter of preference as to which operations to state here.  Personally, I always use the absolute value sign in these cases since it makes it easier for the reader to immediately see that the quantity under discussion is non-negative.